# WooCommerce Checkout add-on plugin: Get the a custom field value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, orders

With WooCommerce I use the plugin [WooCommerce Checkout add-on](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-checkout-add-ons/) that add extra field to the checkout page.

I add a field named **`'livraison'`** and it's saved id DB, but I can't get it with the code :

```
get_post_meta( $order->id, 'livraison', true );
```

I don't understand why is false...

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue:

**1) Checking in your database within `wp_postmeta` table.**

You should make a search sticking this SQL search in SQL query window:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '%livraison%'
```

Because is possible that the **`meta_key`** slug of this custom field is for example **`'_livraison'`**.

If you get nothing, you should check with another search for **a defined order ID** (for example below we search for order ID **`1216`**):

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = 1216
```

Then you will get all the meta data for this order and you will search visually for this custom field.

---

**2) Making sure that you get an Order ID using **`$order->id`** with **`get_post_meta()`** function.**

Depending where you are using **`get_post_meta()`** you need to be sure that  **`$order->id`** isn't **`null`**.

You should try to output before in your code **`$order->id`** value for example with:

```
echo 'Current Order ID is ' . $order->id;
```

If you don't get any order Id, here is the problem. In some WooCommerce hooks you can use for example **`$order_id`** instead, depending on the arguments of the hook used. Same thing for some templates.

> It could be useful, to get better helped, **you provide the code or some extra information** concerning **where** you are trying to use **`get_post_meta( $order->id, 'livraison', true );`**